# Android - How to show warning dialog below confirm dialog?

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I have confirm dialog(A) and warning dialog(B).

`Dialog A` already show on top.

An event come, `dialog B` will show on.

I want `dialog B` will show below `dialog A`.

Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. There is not enough detail here to provide an informed answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for how to ask an effective question.

Comment: You wanna display both dialog box simultaneously ? or you wanna dismiss A and show B?

Comment: @FaridHaq Yes, I wana display both of dialog box simultaneously

Comment: why dont you  just make a dialog A with warning message . and on event trigger just set visibility on of that warning message